# Combine Lists Keyword combining char by char instead of element by element in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I have list

> @{x}=[ABC]

and want to combine with list

> @{Y}=[Donkey]

so i am using keyword

> @{Z}=       Combine Lists   @{x}   @{Y}

Expected Result: @{Z}= [ABC,Donkey]

Finally output of @{Z} is like combining character by character [A,B,C,D,o,n,k,e,y] instead of [ABC,Donkey].
I am using Collection lib of Robotframework 2.7.7 (python).
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When calling [Combine Lists](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#Combine%20Lists), you must give the lists as scalar variables - use `$` rather than `@`. When you use `@` robot will expand the list *before* calling the keyword, which you don't want.

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | Collections

*** Variables ***
| @{x} | ABC
| @{Y} | Donkey

*** Test Cases ***
| Example of combining lists
| | @{expected}= | Create List | ABC | Donkey
| | @{Z}= | Combine lists | ${X} | ${Y}
| | # notice use of $:      ^      ^
| | Lists should be equal | ${Z} | ${expected}
```